# Fnding horizontal asymptotes of $f(x)= \sqrt {9x^2+2x}-3x$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, gre-exam

How to find the Horizontal asymptote for this function:

$f(x)= \sqrt {9x^2+2x}-3x$

I have tried to find the lim where x goes to infinity and negative infinity then what ?

Comment: This function hasn't horizontal asymptote...

Comment: Did you mean $\sqrt{9x^2+2x}-3x$?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant $f(x)=\sqrt{9x^2+2x}-3x$, we can write
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{9x^2+2x}-3x
&=\left(\sqrt{9x^2+2x}-3x\right)\frac{\sqrt{9x^2+2x}+3x}{\sqrt{9x^2+2x}+3x}\\
&=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{9x^2+2x}+3x}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{9+2/x}+3}\\
&\to\frac13
\end{align}
$$
The technique of multiplying $\left(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\right)$ by $\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$ to get $\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$ is very useful in a number of problems.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?